# If edit text is "word" turn the edit text green

Tags: java, android, colors, android-edittext

```
final String a="cout";
    Button okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.OK);
    okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Vprasanje1);
            String value = text.getText().toString();
            if(value == a)
            {
                EditText banana = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Vprasanje1);
                banana.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
```

This is the code I've come up with, I just started programing in Java and have no clue what to do atm.

Comment: Don't compare String values using `==`. Use `equals()`.

Comment: this question could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :
Compare String using `.equals` or `.equalsIgnoreCase` method.

```
final String a="cout";
    Button okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.OK);
    okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Vprasanje1);
            String value = text.getText().toString();
            if(value.equals(a))
            {
                EditText banana = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Vprasanje1);
                banana.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
```